# UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification delivered after entering foreground

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiapplication, nsnotification

I register my VC for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

However the notification gets triggered when the app enters foreground, not when it entered background

I assume

- that the notification callback happens in next run loop, however, when the app enters background, this next runloop is executed when the app enters foreground

**Is there any workaround for this to act really on Entering background?**

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: allright, but there is nothing special on the relevant code as registering for the notification

Comment: I use that notification in several classes and in every case the selector is called as the app enters the background.

Comment: are you sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification instead, that's when it's *about* to move to the background.  Otherwise, I could answer you better about why it's not getting called until the app becomes active if you add some of your code to the question.